# Hide parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML;

```
<div class="pagination__page" data-pagination-page="" data-pagination-group="group-0" style="display: block;">
    <div class="question">
        <h2 class="question__title">Country</h2>
        <div class="form-field form-field--dropdown">
            <select required="1" name="country" data-parsley-group="group-0">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Please select...</option>
                <option value="great-britain">Great Britain</option>
                <option value="zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question"> // line 13
        <h2 class="question__title">Postcode</h2>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input data-parsley-postcode="1" name="postcode" type="text" data-parsley-group="group-0">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I hide the div starting on "line 13" (see comment in code) unless the Country question above's input is Great Britain?

It's dynamic so I can't assign the div directly to give it a name. All I have to go on is the `input` which has name of `postcode`.

If I **could** access that div, then I think it would be something like;

```
$('#country').on('change.postcode', function() {
  $("#").toggle($(this).val() == 'great-britain');
}).trigger('change.postcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination of `parent` and `next` should do the trick:

```
$(function(){
 $('select[name="country"]').change(function(){
     var country = $(this).val();
   if(country == 'great-britain'){
      $(this).parent().parent().next('.question').show();
   }
   else{
        $(this).parent().parent().next('.question').hide();
   }
 });
});
```

In order to hide the dinamically generated html, you can do something like this:

```
$('.question').each(function(i,item){
    if((i+1) % 2 ==0){
    $(item).hide();
  }
});
```

#### Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/pen942nf/1/

Comment: ah, very useful. do you know how I can hide it to begin with? So, on page load?

Comment: Check the fiddle...it is not visible by default with `<div class="question" style="display:none">`

Comment: I can't change the HTML at that level. As they're created dynamically. But that would usually be the correct solution

Comment: this seems to work though; `$("input[name='postcode']").closest("div.question").hide();`

Answer (score 3):

There is a function in JQuery called `parent()`. You can use get the `input` node via

```
$("input[name='postcode']")
```

and then access the parent of it's parent to hide it like that:

```
$("input[name='postcode']").parent().parent().hide();
```

Learn more about `parent()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/parents/).

EDIT (thanks to  andlrc):

You could also use `closest()` instead of the double `parent()`:

```
$("input[name='postcode']").closest("div.question").hide();
```

see [here](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: You could also consider using `.closest(selector)`.

Answer (score 0):

You This must work:

```
<style>
.hide{display:none;}
</style>

<div class="pagination__page" data-pagination-page="" data-pagination-group="group-0" style="display: block;">
    <div class="question">
        <h2 class="question__title">Country</h2>
        <div class="form-field form-field--dropdown">
            <select required="1" name="country" data-parsley-group="group-0">
                <option selected="selected" value="">Please select...</option>
                <option value="great-britain">Great Britain</option>
                <option value="zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="question sh"> // line 13
        <h2 class="question__title">Postcode</h2>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input data-parsley-postcode="1" name="postcode" type="text" data-parsley-group="group-0">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

 $("#country").change(function(){
$(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
  if($(this).attr("value")=="great-britain"){
    $('.sh').show();
  }
  else{
    $('.sh').hide();
});
});
</script>
```